# StateError (Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close) in bloc_base.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need your help. Just an hour ago this code worked fine, but now I get the error you see in the question

The bottom line is that when I click on the button, I go to the screen where I have to scan the qr code, but when I go to this very screen, I get an error. Help fix it!

Full screen code posted below -

```
    import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:eco_city/features/presentation/scanner/cubit/scanner_cubit.dart';
import 'package:eco_city/features/presentation/scanner/cubit/scanner_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
// import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import '../home/home.dart';

import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';

class QRViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QRViewExampleState createState() => _QRViewExampleState();
}

class _QRViewExampleState extends State<QRViewExample> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;

  // In order to get hot reload to work we need to pause the camera if the platform
  // is android, or resume the camera if the platform is iOS.
  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    print('первая функция');
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      controller!.pauseCamera();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      controller!.resumeCamera();
    }
  }

  getQr(qr) {
    if (qr != null) {
      RegExp exp = RegExp(r"[^0-9]+");
      final stringFormat = qr.code.rawContent.replaceAll(exp, '');
      return stringFormat;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<ScannerCubit>(
      create: (context) => ScannerCubit(),
      child: BlocBuilder<ScannerCubit, ScannerState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is ScannerNotScan) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 5,
                    child: QRView(
                      key: qrKey,
                      onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Center(
                      child: (result != null)
                          ? Text(
                              'Barcode Type: ${describeEnum(result!.format)}   Data: ${result!.code}')
                          : Text('Scan a code'),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (state is ScannerLoading) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            );
          } else if (state is ScannerLoaded) {
            return Home();
          } else if (state is ScannerError) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: Text('4')),
            );
          }
          throw StateError('err');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) async {
    print('последняя функция');
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
        if (result != null) {
          getNextScreen();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void getNextScreen() async {
    if (result != null) {
      await context.read<ScannerCubit>().scanner(getQr(result!.code));
      // log(await getQr(result!.code.toString()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

and my cubit -

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:eco_city/features/data/scanner/scanner_models.dart';
import 'package:eco_city/features/presentation/scanner/cubit/scanner_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../../config.dart';

class ScannerCubit extends Cubit<ScannerState> {
  ScannerCubit() : super(ScannerNotScan());

  Future<void> scanner(String qr) async {
    emit(ScannerLoading());

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = prefs.getString('token');

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ConfigUrl.sendQrCodeScanner),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
          "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
          "qr_code": qr,
        }));
    if(isClosed) return; 
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      log(qr);
      final responseJson = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      emit(ScannerLoaded(scannerModel: ScannerModel.fromJson(responseJson)));
    } else {
      log(qr);
      log(response.statusCode.toString());
      log(json.decode(response.body).toString());
      emit(ScannerError());
    } 
  }
}
```

Sometimes my screen is replaced well, but often with an error

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't place the BlocProvider inside the stateful widget. Like this, the provider becomes re-created on every new build, for example if the scan provides no result.

Try to create an upstream widget (above QRViewExample) and place the provider there.

Comment: Can you add a small example please?

Comment: just wanted to add an example, but when copying your code I noticed that you have already edited your code and placed the provider upstream - if I am not mistaken. So this did not help? One other point that looks suspicious, you `return Home()`. I think you should rather `pop` the current page. Otherwise you would have the tree Home > Scanner > Home. Otherwise, try to remove some sequences of your code and see when you get the app running stable again.

Comment: I can substitute any widget there instead of the main one, and it will not work, apparently the error is in another
It would be great if you vote YES my question